# Getting data from one table if not also in another

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

I've got a database with two relevant tables (**times** and **registrations**).

I want to get the times from the **times** table, through an SQL query, that aren't in the **registrations** table (don't have a registration on them). Registration at 5PM, wouldn't show 5PM from **times** in the query.

My current query is:

```
SELECT time FROM `times` WHERE time IN (SELECT time FROM `registrations` WHERE ID IS NOT NULL)
```

(registrations DO have an ID)

This does the opposite of what I want it to do (shows all times, regardless of registration, or not).
How could I get the opposite effect?

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to want `not exists`:

```
select t.*
from times t
where not exists (select 1 from regisrations r where r.time = t.time)
```